# 1000baseT/Full Supported and Advertised but not working

Tags: networking

I see there's an issue like this that was closed. It was solved by replacing the cable.
I have this issue and I suspect it's not a hardware problem.
Here is my sudo lshw -C network:

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 07
   serial: b8:ca:3a:ca:44:6d
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.045.08-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.128 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:27 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d1404000-d1404fff memory:d1400000-d1403fff
```

Here is sudo ethtool enp7s0:

```
Settings for enp7s0:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: yes
```

I can only think it's not a hardware problem because I've recently had it running before (same laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, same router and same cable), this was sudo ethtool enps70:

```
Settings for enp7s0:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: yes
```

But now I can't set speed to 1000

Comment: Why do you suspect it's not hardware?

Comment: As I posted, I've recently had speed set at 1000 (see the last ethtool printout) and since then I've only had system updates and reboots, everything else is the same, (same machine and Ubuntu system, the same CAT5E clable, same router with same firmware and settings). Now I can't change speed with ethtool, it autonegotiates to 100, I understand.